# db_query('SELECT nid FROM uc_products'); doesn't give any results! Why?

Tags: 6, ubercart, database

There's a really simple query related to the **enabled and working** Ubercart, where the task is to get all the nids from `uc_products` table, which simply doesn't give any results:

```
$query = 'SELECT nid FROM uc_products';
$result = db_query($query);
dsm('===================================================');
dsm($query);
while ($nid = db_result($result)) {
    dsm('$nid: '.$nid);
}
```

BUT when I run the very **same query** in the same database **in phpMyAdmin**, **it works**, and it gives me ALL the correct results (I have 8 products now).

[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot]

BUT the following queries work correctly, and give me all the expected results (the first is the strangest, because `vid` field is of the same type, but only has another name):

```
$query = 'SELECT vid FROM uc_products';
$result = db_query($query);
dsm('===================================================');
dsm($query);
while ($vid = db_result($result)) {
    dsm('$vid: '.$vid);
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM uc_products';
$result = db_query($query);
dsm('===================================================');
dsm($query);
while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    dsm('$row->nid: '.$row->nid);
}

$query = 'SELECT nid FROM node';
$result = db_query($query);
dsm('===================================================');
dsm($query);
while ($nid = db_result($result)) {
    dsm('$nid: '.$nid);
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the test results:

[image: screenshot of the tests]

As you can see, the first two queries don't return any results, while the others work correctly.
This is a really strange problem. I didn't modify the core modules, so I don't understand the situation. It doesn't matter whether I run it on localhost or my ongoing public server, the result is the same. This means that [`uc_order_condition_has_products_form()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ubercart!uc_order!uc_order.ca.inc/function/uc_order_condition_has_products_form/6) in Conditional Actions menu doesn't work correctly either. I've never ever met such problems in Drupal.

**Does anyone have a clue where I should start debugging?**

Comment: Just FYI, your code works perfectly for me on 3 Drupal 6 Ubercart sites (I've just copy/pasted your code into '/devel/php/' and all of the nids were outputted in the messages area as expected) so it's definitely specific to your installation. Very strange

Comment: @Clive: thanks for your answer, yes, you're absolutely right, I forgot to tell that I also tested it in another "clear" Drupal 6.22 (the same "old" version) which I use for just testing, and there it works absolutely fine. But I can't even imagine what kind of problem there could be in this version of Drupal, because - as far as I remember - I didn't modify Drupal's core modules. So I simply don't understand. I should update my Drupal, but it still doesn't explain why `node` ids work, `uc_products` ids don't. But maybe an update could remove any kind of messy stuffs, I don't have a clue...

Comment: @Clive: please see my updated question... `SELECT * FROM uc_products` works perfectly as it should... :-O The previously mentioned `SELECT nid FROM uc_products` still doesn't.

Comment: @Clive: FYI, `SELECT vid FROM uc_products` also works correctly too! Why can Drupal have such a problem with the `nid` field?

Comment: turn on the devel module and enable the qury logging at admin/settings/devel - that will show what queries are being run on the page. Maybe that query is getting modified somehow along the way?

Comment: @greggles: thanks for the tip, greggles, but unfortunately the problem is the same, because the query hasn't been modified: http://i.imgur.com/5JYsY.png, so it's still a really mysterious "bug" (or don't know how to call it). :((

Comment: What about `SELECT vid, nid FROM uc_products`? And whilst it's not quite as efficient if `SELECT *` is working then why not just stick with that?

Comment: `SELECT nid` is often going to be significantly more efficient than `SELECT *`. If the specified columns are indexed, they are likely fetched from RAM, as opposed to disc. And if the query is called often, you can completely break a site with a previously fine `SELECT *` by adding a new column that may make the * more expensive than it was before.

Comment: While I don't see how it would be the issue in this case, don't select on tables without {} around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is likely because your first result is a "0" and php will evaluate that as a False, which stops your while loop from running.

Comment: Wow, it was a long time ago... I can't test that site anymore, but you're right! :D I think I didn't notice back then that the first `nid`'s value was really equal to `0`, which shouldn't happen, so it's unexpected in my opinion (0 as a node id doesn't really make sense, it should start from 1) - but it really can stop the while loop immediately. Thanks! +1 and accepted. :)